# Ruby ternary operator without else

Tags: ruby, operators, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Is there a ruby idiom for "If  do-this," and "do-this" just as a simple command?

for example, I'm currently doing

```
object.method ? a.action : nil
```

to leave the else clause empty, but I feel like there's probably a more idiomatic way of doing this that doesn't involve having to specify a nil at the end. (and alternatively, I feel like taking up multiple lines of code would be wasteful in this case.

Comment: It depends on the context, but sometimes it's more elegant to read an if/while/begin block with only one line in the body than something more dense/terse.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
a.action if object.method?
```

Answer (score 142):

As a general rule: you pretty much never need the ternary operator in Ruby. The reason why you need it in C, is because in C `if` is a statement, so if you want to return a value you *have* to use the ternary operator, which is an expression.

In Ruby, *everything* is an expression, there *are* no statements, which makes the ternary operator pretty much superfluous. You can always replace

```
cond ? then_branch : else_branch
```

with

```
if cond then then_branch else else_branch end
```

So, in your example:

```
object.method ? a.action : nil
```

is equivalent to

```
if object.method then a.action end
```

which as @Greg Campbell points out is in turn equivalent to the trailing `if` modifier form

```
a.action if object.method
```

Also, since the boolean operators in Ruby not just return `true` or `false`, but the value of the last evaluated expression, you can use them for control flow. This is an idiom imported from Perl, and would look like this:

```
object.method and a.action
```

Comment: ternary operator `cond ? a : b` is shorter than `if cond then a else b end`, that alone makes me use it to save 11 chars ;-)

Comment: [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#ternary-operator) states: "Favor the ternary operator (`?:`) over `if/then/else/end` constructs. It's more common and obviously more concise".

Answer (score 18):

Greg's answer is the best, but for the record, and even more than in C, expressions and statements are equivalent in Ruby, so besides `a.action if o.m?` you can also do things like:

```
object.method? && a.action
```

You can write `(a; b; c) if d` or even

```
(a
 b
 c
) if d
```

or for that matter: `(x; y; z) ? (a; b c) : (d; e; f)`

There is no situation in Ruby where only a single statement or expression is allowed...

Answer (score 4):

`result = (<expression> && <true value>) || <false value>`

`value = 1
result = (value == 1 && 'one' ) || 'two'
result #=> 'one'`
Explain: value == 1 && 'one' #=> returns last expression result, value is equals 1 so and section will be evaluated, and return 'one'.

`value = 0
result = (value == 1 && 'one' ) || 'two'
result #=> 'two'`

Explain: value != 1 and 'and' expression will not be evaluated, but instad will be used 'or' expression and it returns 'two'

Answer (score 1):

Another way this can be done on the same line is:

```
if object.method; a.action end
```

This is considered bad style by Rubocop because it uses a semicolon to terminate the expression, but I find it more readable in some conditions than tacking on the if statement at the end.  It is easier to overlook an if statement at the end and I don't always want to return something if the condition isn't true(as you are forced into with a ternary operator).

You can also be a bit more verbose and rubocop friendly:

```
if object.method then a.action end
```