# what does this line of code from form_for method in rails do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

what does this line of code do it is from the form_for method in rails ?

> object = record.is_a?(Array) ? record.last : record

Answer (score 2):

First off, [here is the actual line of code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L424), and the full context:

```
def form_for(record, options = {}, &block)
  raise ArgumentError, "Missing block" unless block_given?
  html_options = options[:html] ||= {}

  case record
  when String, Symbol
    object_name = record
    object = nil
  else
    object = record.is_a?(Array) ? record.last : record
    raise ArgumentError, "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" unless object
    object_name = options[:as] || model_name_from_record_or_class(object).param_key
    apply_form_for_options!(record, object, options)
  end
  [...]
end
```

It says: if `record` is an array, then assign the last element of the array to `object`, otherwise assign `record` itself to `object`.

So basically, it describes how to handle the case when you don't know whether you'll be getting an array of records or just one record.

There are a couple of cases where you pass an array into `form_for`.

Namespaced routes:

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @post]) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Nested resources:

```
<%= form_for([@document, @comment]) do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

Note that in each case, it's the last element in the array that the form is actually for; the earlier elements provide context (on either namespaces or nesting). More in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).

Answer (score 0):

It checks if the variable `record` is an array, and if it is, gets the last element in the array, and if it isn't gets the record itself.

This is useful for nested routing, for instance if you had a model Book that belongs to User, and in your routes you nest them:

```
# config/routes.rb

resources :users do
  resources :books
end
```

Then for the resource you'd need to specify `form_for [@user, @book] do |f|`

---

More on form_for with nested resources: [form_for with nested resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034700/form-for-with-nested-resources#answer-4611932)

Also it uses the is_a? method: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F

And the ternary operator: [Ruby ternary operator without else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174419/ruby-ternary-operator-without-else#answer-2175392)